# Null pointer Exception in Apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, exception, null-pointer

I am getting "FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" in Apex controller when i click on update link pop up. Its showing in query with " ulstAsset ".I am newbie to apex coding. please help on this. code is below

```
public void UpdateLicense() {
    //Get existing values for Update System (Admin) screen
    System.debug('Log ::: UpdateLicense Enters');
    selReplaceReason = 'select';
    isReplacement = false;
    strMsg = '';

    if (ubaseAsset != null) {
        uTotalQty = string.ValueOf(ubaseAsset.NEX_Quantity__c);
        uAvailableQty = string.ValueOf(ubaseAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c);
    }

    if(sysID != null) {
        NEX_System__c osystem = [
            SELECT NEX_System_State__c, NEX_Sub_state__c, NEX_Platform_OEM__c, 
                NEX_Product_Version__c, NEX_Comments__c, NEX_Friendly_Name__c 
            FROM NEX_System__c where id=:sysID
        ];

        selSysStatus = osystem.NEX_System_State__c;
        selSysSubState = osystem.NEX_Sub_state__c;
        selSysSupportedBy = osystem.NEX_Platform_OEM__c;        
        systemProdVersion = osystem.NEX_Product_Version__c;
        sysInternalComments = osystem.NEX_Comments__c;                    
    }


    ulstAsset = [
        Select Id, NEX_Available_Quantity__c, 
            NEX_Quantity__c, NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__r.EndDate,
            Product2.NEX_License_Sub_Type__c, NEX_Unit_Of_Measure__c, 
            Product2.NEX_License_Option_Name__c 
        from Asset 
        where NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__c =: ubaseAsset.NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__c 
            and Active__c = TRUE
    ];

    if(ulstAsset.size() > 0) {
        for(Asset oAsset: ulstAsset) {
            string type = oAsset.Product2.NEX_License_Sub_Type__c;

            if(type == 'OptionHA') {
                uhasHA = (oAsset.NEX_Quantity__c > 0) ? 
                    true : false; 
                availableHA = (oAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c > 0) ? 
                    true : false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the line where you are getting the exception will help here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to verify those fields are not null prior to checking their value.  I would think the changes below would resolve the issue

```
        if(ubaseAsset != null)
    {
        uTotalQty = (ubaseAsset.NEX_Quantity__c == null)?0:string.ValueOf(ubaseAsset.NEX_Quantity__c);
        uAvailableQty = (ubaseAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c == null)?0:string.ValueOf(ubaseAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c);
    }
    if(sysID != null)
    {
        NEX_System__c osystem = [Select NEX_System_State__c,NEX_Sub_state__c,NEX_Platform_OEM__c,NEX_Product_Version__c,NEX_Comments__c, NEX_Friendly_Name__c from NEX_System__c where id=:sysID];
        selSysStatus = osystem.NEX_System_State__c;
        selSysSubState = osystem.NEX_Sub_state__c;
        selSysSupportedBy = osystem.NEX_Platform_OEM__c;        
        systemProdVersion = osystem.NEX_Product_Version__c;
        sysInternalComments = osystem.NEX_Comments__c;                    
    }


ulstAsset = [Select Id,NEX_Available_Quantity__c,NEX_Quantity__c,NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__r.EndDate,Product2.NEX_License_Sub_Type__c,NEX_Unit_Of_Measure__c, Product2.NEX_License_Option_Name__c from Asset where NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__c =: ubaseAsset.NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__c and Active__c = TRUE];

if(ulstAsset.size() > 0)
{
    for(Asset oAsset: ulstAsset)
    {
        string type = oAsset.Product2.NEX_License_Sub_Type__c;
        if(type != null && type == 'OptionHA')
        {
            uhasHA = (oAsset.NEX_Quantity__c != null && oAsset.NEX_Quantity__c > 0)? true:false; //If option is active
            availableHA = (oAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c != null && oAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c > 0)? true:false; //If units are available
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the rep @SFDC Nob its throwing error "Incompatible types in ternary operator: String, Integer at line 2,932 column 26 
"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check if is **ubaseAsset** null but then later you use it even if it is null in your query. What you need to do is put everything into your if statement so that if it is null you don't attempt to do anything.

You should repeat this every time you query so if you're query returns nothing, stop processing. I'd also reccomend throwing exceptions in these cases:

```
public void UpdateLicense() {
    //Get existing values for Update System (Admin) screen
    System.debug('Log ::: UpdateLicense Enters');
    selReplaceReason = 'select';
    isReplacement = false;
    strMsg = '';

    if (ubaseAsset != null) {
        uTotalQty = string.ValueOf(ubaseAsset.NEX_Quantity__c);
        uAvailableQty = string.ValueOf(ubaseAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c);

        if(sysID != null) {
            NEX_System__c osystem = [
                SELECT NEX_System_State__c, NEX_Sub_state__c, NEX_Platform_OEM__c, 
                    NEX_Product_Version__c, NEX_Comments__c, NEX_Friendly_Name__c 
                FROM NEX_System__c where id=:sysID
            ];

            if (osystem != null) {
                selSysStatus = osystem.NEX_System_State__c;
                selSysSubState = osystem.NEX_Sub_state__c;
                selSysSupportedBy = osystem.NEX_Platform_OEM__c;        
                systemProdVersion = osystem.NEX_Product_Version__c;
                sysInternalComments = osystem.NEX_Comments__c;  
            }            
            // I don't think you want an exception here             
        }
        // I don't think you want an exception here 

        ulstAsset = [
            Select Id, NEX_Available_Quantity__c, 
                NEX_Quantity__c, NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__r.EndDate,
                Product2.NEX_License_Sub_Type__c, NEX_Unit_Of_Measure__c, 
                Product2.NEX_License_Option_Name__c 
            from Asset 
            where NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__c =: ubaseAsset.NEX_Lnk_Entitlement__c 
                and Active__c = TRUE
        ];

        if(ulstAsset != null && !ulstAsset.isEmpty) {
            for(Asset oAsset : ulstAsset) {
                string type = oAsset.Product2.NEX_License_Sub_Type__c;

                if(type == 'OptionHA') {
                    uhasHA = (oAsset.NEX_Quantity__c > 0) ? 
                        true : false; 
                    availableHA = (oAsset.NEX_Available_Quantity__c > 0) ? 
                        true : false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Throw new CustomException('ulstAsset is null or empty');
        }
    } else {
        Throw new CustomException('ubaseAsset is null');
    }
}

public class CustomException extends Exception{}
```

The exceptions are primarily to communicate you you (the developer) when something goes wrong. If you want it to fail with no errors you can remove them.